# Jquery mobile is not working in phonegap android application

Tags: android, eclipse, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am trying to building an android app with jquery mobile in phonegap . My code is working well in browser , but when I tried to run it on android emulator it is not working . This is how it looks on browser and in android emulator

http://i58.tinypic.com/2ci8pl0.jpg

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>View Source</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/jquery.mobile.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/mystyles.css" />
    <script src="_/js/jquery.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script src="_/js/myscript.js"></script>
    <script src="_/js/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
</head>
```

This is the head section of my index.html file .

I have linked all the files correctly .  But I don't know whats the problem

Comment: what does the underscore reference to in your scripts and css includes? Did you actually put files in www/_/js and www/_/css ?

Comment: yes . I put files there

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same problem and was struggling with it for a whole day until I decided to run on an actual android device and....
Problem is gone!

Must be an emulator issue.